# Does Anthony really have this personality trait?

Tags: gunnerkrigg-court

Many people in the Gunnerkrigg Court fandom seem to take it as a given that Anthony, Antimony's father, is literally incapable of expressing his true personality in any group larger than one person. If he's with a single person, he'll behave normally, even if they're a stranger; if any more are present, he immediately becomes completely withdrawn, no matter how well he knows them. Comments to this effect show up every time a strip involving Anthony is posted.

However, I don't recall reading this, and I can't find any reference to it on the wiki. It always seemed to me that Anthony was just a socially awkward and distant person, and that while he probably loosened up in smaller groups, there was no "rule" to it - that he could be distant with individuals, as he was with Antimony, or even possibly relaxed in the right group, and that it all depended on how comfortable he was.

Was this particular personality trait of Tony ever explicitly confirmed?

Comment: Problem is, there was no such group...

Comment: @Mithoron - Perhaps. But the people who adhere to this theory would hold that he's literally incapable of expressing himself with two people, even if he's comfortable with them individually. For instance, that he'd be fine chatting with Kat or Mr. Donlan, but put them in the same room and he'd be unable to express himself.

Comment: Since most of the comic is told from Antimony's perspective, most of the time we see him being withdrawn and formal with two people, one of them is her (and he's definitely got some issue with her). That always seemed like the more obvious thing to me, keeping in mind that he's not so social to begin with.

Comment: Gah, what people have with incapable, impossible etc. Getting certain level of intimacy with two people instead of one is harder. I think he needs to remove certain mental blockade and it's just harder for talking in trio, not like "impossible", but you'd need two "right" people and circumstances. There were maybe such short moments in comics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, this was explicitly confirmed.

In [chapter 64](https://www.gunnerkrigg.com/?p=1899) which describes how Anthony and Surma fell in love, Anthony says

> I can't be myself when I'm around more than one person.

He doesn't really know why.  It hasn't been explored whether this is simply an extreme manifestation of social anxiety, or if he has some sort of specific mental block related to being in the presence of multiple people, or if there's some other, more supernatural explanation.

It's possible that Tony was exaggerating his behavior, and that he's capable of behaving normally in the presence of multiple people if he's extremely close to all of them (Donald and Surma at the same time, for example).  But if this is the case, we've never seen it.

On the other hand, we've never seen him exclusively in the presence of people he was comfortable with when multiple other people were present (in the present day, Annie was frequently present, who he was uncomfortable with in all situations, and in the past Eglamore was usually present in group events.

It is notable that in the most recent scenes (Chapter 69) he was rather formal, but in [today's page](https://www.gunnerkrigg.com/?p=2090) he appears to be relaxed in the sole presence of "Forest Annie", the member of the group he was least comfortable with.  This gives support to the idea that his behavior is more than a matter of shutting down to level of the person he is least comfortable with, and that he shuts down even if he's close to everyone present.

### Update:

Chapter 80, [The Mind Cage](https://www.gunnerkrigg.com/?p=2440), dives into depth about how Anthony's mind works, and confirms beyond all doubt that his ability to communicate is tied to the number of people present.  Whether this is psychological or supernatural stull remains to be seen.

Comment: Still more recently, he appears to be making some progress: witness his [smile of relief](https://www.gunnerkrigg.com/?p=2540) that Annie is safe, which continues even when Kat and Renard come over.